# passing '=' in arguments to windows batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I ran into trouble when passing an argument that ends with an = sign to batch files. Consider this (> being the Windows XP prompt):

```
> type c.bat
echo %1

> c.bat bla=
bla

> c.bat "bla="
"bla="
```

Why is the `=` in `bla=` swallowed? And how am I supposed to pass an = sign in an argument?

Answer (score 7):

It is a known problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/35938

You can bypass it like this:

```
SET ARG1=bla= && your.bat && SET ARG1=
```

and your.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO %ARG1%
```

Alternatively you can pass it as a quoted parameter (using "" around it):

```
your.bat "bla="
```

and then use it in the batch file as follows:

```
echo %~1
```

The `~` there in this case just removes the quotes.

Comment: The 'unquoting' via `%~1` is key, also when you want to pass something to your function via `call :my_function_label "%my_var_with_ugly_chars"` - without quotes you'll get the first token of the argument as `%1`, and with them, you need to remove quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Read the doc:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true

"The following special characters require quotation marks: & < > [ ] { } ^ = ; ! ' + , ` ~ [white space]"

Comment: Thank you! But this says that there is trouble with = , but not what exactly happens here (windows does not complain that there is anything wrong with the command), nor how I can pass bla= .

Comment: You can pass blah= by putting the argument within quotation marks, like in your last example.

Comment: Not quite - then I am passing "bla=" - including the quotation marks - and not just bla= as I wish. But the other answer indicates there is actually no solution.

Comment: @hstoerr: You can use the argument with `%~1` in the batch which strips the quotes. I have edited it into the other answer since the original author apparently didn't know that.

Comment: The characters []{}+ doesn't require quotation marks, the cmd help is not completly correct here

Comment: @Joey: unfortunately, editing the called batch file is not possible in my case, since the other batch file is part of a software distribution. I've reported a bug there, but that will take time... :-(

Comment: @hstoerr why not just create a wrapper batch script that properly passes the equal sign to the other batch file?

Comment: @Foo Bah That is precisely what I tried but failed to do. 8-) I can pass "bla=" (including the quotes), but not bla= .

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
your.bat "bla="

------ your.bat ----
echo %~1
```

or also

```
your.bat bla=

------ your.bat ----
echo %*
```

The best solution is case dependent.

A description is at

```
call /?
```

Normally it's better to enclose problematic parameters into quotes and remove the quotes later with the `%~` modifier.
The `set "param1=%~1"` uses the fact, that `%~1` will remove enclosing quotes when they exists.
And the quotes around `"param1=%~1"` ensure that special charaters will not produce errors.

```
call :myFunc "<Hard>=&|"
exit /b

:myFunc
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "param1=%~1"
echo(!param1!
exit /b
```

But with quotes inside the parameter, problems can still occours.

```
call :myFunc "&"^&""
```

Comment: Many thanks for the `%*` alternative - now, for 1-argument "batch functions" I can use `call :my_function_label %my_var_with_ugly_chars` and in the function refer to `%*`, where I need the part after function label (it's "all arguments", like bash's `$*`, right?).

Comment: @TomaszGandor Yes, but it's easier and safer to use `call :myFunc "<>~=;"` and expand this with `set "myVar=%~1"`

Answer (score 0):

will this do it?

If tem.cmd contains

```
@echo off
set param=%1
set param=%param:"=%
echo %param%
```

then

```
c:\> tem.cmd "hi="
```

gives

```
hi=
```

Comment: Note: `echo %~1` does the same :-)